Targeting `span` element with no text behind it
In this HTML:
<p><span>lorem</span> with text after</p>
<p>with text before <span>lorem</span></p>

Is there a CSS selector that will target only the first span element (the one with no text before it) and not the second?

No there is not... raw text is not an element and so it cannot be, erm, "not selected".
